# How to run GTK+ in ubuntu?

Tags: gtk

How to run GTK+ in ubuntu. When I enter gtk+ in the terminal then it doesn't open. 
Neither I found any application as GTK. It doesn't run in the terminal.

Comment: I would get started using `zenity`. You can search this site for examples.

Answer (score 1):

GTK+ is toolkit  or framework to provide user interface support. Like awt, swing or JavaFX in java.

And as mentioned on their website https://www.gtk.org/

> GTK+ is cross-platform and boasts an easy to use API, speeding up your development time. Take a look at the screenshots to see a number of platforms GTK+ will run.

you can use [Glade builder](https://glade.gnome.org/) to build the interface for your app.

Some of the Desktop Environments like Cinnamon, Mate, Gnome use GTK framework and already have it. **Installing from source can cause conflicts with your system and may crash it.**